# Convert vector of single integers into vector of single binary values

Tags: rust

If I have a vector that represents some arbitrarily big numbers, `big_v`, I want to be able to convert this vector into a vector that holds the binary representation of `big_v` as well in order to implement a division algorithm. So say

```
let big_v = vec![1,3,9];        // 139
let big_binary_v = func(big_v); // 10001011
```

`big_binary_v`'s value would be the equivalent of `[1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1]`.

---

This trick is that I could implement this easy if it weren't for the fact that the vector can represent an arbitrarily large integer , if not I could simply do `binary(100) + binary(30) + binary(9)`. In the case that you have a number like `100000000000000001` however, you can't compute `binary(100000000000000000) + binary(1)`. Is there any trick to convert this vector to binary without using size dependent operations?

Comment: A vector of bits is an awfully inefficient representation. Consider writing accessor methods that operate on your `Vec<u32>` (or whatever), accessing and setting individual bits of the digits. That assumes your digits are bundles of bits rather than decimal digits, but honestly there is rarely a good reason to *not* do that.

Comment: @delnan I assumed that OP wasn't worried about maximum efficiency here, but was mostly using this as a learning exercise. Otherwise, I'd assume that there's a arbitrary precision library available that could be used (but I haven't looked). However, the description of the question could be clarified.

Comment: @Shepmaster The change I propose is not a very complicated one, though, and it easily saves a factor of eight in memory (and for many algorithms, the associated increase in cache hits will be pretty big as well).

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious way is to generate some abstract operations.

```
fn add_binary_fixed(left: &mut Vec<u8>, right: u8);
fn multiply_binary_fixed(binary_value: &mut Vec<u8>, by: u8);
```

Then one can do

```
let mut binary_value = vec![0];
for decimal_digit in decimal_value {
    multiply(binary_value, 10);
    add(binary_value, decimal_digit);
}
binary_value
```

If one uses traits and proper types, this can generalize to any (bounded, natural numbered) base conversion:

```
fn convert(value: &LargeInteger, base: u8) -> LargeInteger {
    let mut output = LargeInteger::new(base);
    for digit in value {
        output.multiply(base);
        output.add(digit);
    }
    output
}
```